# Why can the X-Frame-Options not hide the iframe web in Chrome (117.0.5938.88), but it works in Safari?

Tags: x-frame-options

```
<iframe src="https://developer.mozilla.org/" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

in html5 local.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9Fd.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhcG.png)

I wrote this page locally. When I open it in Safari, it behaves as expected – it does not appear in the frame, and the console shows an error

> Refused to display 'https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY.'

However, in Chrome, it does appear. How can I achieve the same result in Chrome?

Expecting: Chrome and Safari behave the same。